# Want to add my android pkpass viewer app in "OpenWith" popup

Tags: xamarin.android

Implementing Xamarin android viewer app. Whenever I will download pkpass file, I just want to add my app in "Open with" Popup same as passes, passandroid apps appear.

Comment: You should add `IntentFilter` like this link.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53507479/open-any-jpg-image-using-my-application-xamarin-android, but you should change the MIME type https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14559959/pkpass-on-android

Comment: @ Leon Lu - MSFT : Thank you so much. Its working. How to get same pass in activity, when app open after choose my app in "openwith" popup

Comment: Do you want to get same result, when you open your pkpass viewer app? Does this  pass store in local file?

Comment: yes, Pass is already downloaded and I want to get same pass but how to get that one?